# Merging dictionaries using a counter

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

I have the following dictionaries (example):

```
>>> x = {'a': 'foo', 'b': 'foobar'}
>>> y = {'c': 'barfoo', 'd': 'bar'}
```

I want to take the `keys` of each and make them the value of another `dict`, say `z`, such that the `keys` of `z` is an incremented counter, equal to the length of both the `dicts`.

```
>>> z = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}
```

As you can notice, the `keys` of `z` is an incremented counter and the `values` are the `keys` of `x` and `y`.

How do I achieve this? I have tried various solutions and playing with `zip`, but none seem to work. Probably because I have to update the `z` dict in succession.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [1]: import itertools
In [2]: x = {'a': 'foo', 'b': 'foobar'}
In [3]: y = {'c': 'barfoo', 'd': 'bar'}

In [4]: z = [key for key in itertools.chain(x, y)]

In [5]: z
Out[5]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

In [6]: dict(enumerate(z))
Out[6]: {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd'}

In [7]: dict(enumerate(z, 1))
Out[7]: {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}
```

If you want duplicate keys to occur only once, replace `[4]` with this:

```
z = set(key for key in itertools.chain(x, y))
```

Note that you also could do everything at once (for this example I've added `'a': 'meow'` to `y`):

```
In [15]: dict(enumerate(set(key for key in itertools.chain(x, y)), 1))
Out[15]: {1: 'a', 2: 'c', 3: 'b', 4: 'd'}

In [16]: dict(enumerate((key for key in itertools.chain(x, y)), 1))
Out[16]: {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'a', 4: 'c', 5: 'd'}
```

Comment: +1, beautiful! A really elegant solution. I never thought about the `dict(enumerate)` part.

Comment: Now it's even more elegant ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
import itertools as it
{i+1:k for i,k in enumerate(it.chain(x,y))}
# {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}
```

Note that dict- (and related set-) comprehensions are new in v2.7+.

Comment: Nice, I somehow overlooked the `chain` part completely.

Comment: Note that dict comprehensions require python 2.7 - in older python versions you'd need `dict((i+1, k) for ...)` instead of `{i+1:k for ...}`